Can you place an Indesign document into photoshop as a smart object?
I have recently learnt I can use an illustrator file as a smart object in photoshop and you can open in Illustator and make changes which will update in photoshop. Just wondering if you can do the same with an Indesign document?

Hi. Have you tried?  Surely that would answer your question.

No. Not Indesign native files. Phothsop does not see them as "readable files".
But.. you can place a PDF as a smart object. So you could export the Indd file as a PDF and use that. But I don't know if that will help.
